# How to hide the column header of a particular list?

Tags: column, list-form

Please help,

How do I hide the column header of a particular list? I have several lists on the same page so I can't really use this code.

Hide Column Header

```
<style type="text/css">

  .ms-viewheadertr
  {
     display: none
  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use javascript, just use id and class selector in css like you just had it.

```
<style type="text/css">

  #scriptWPQ1 .ms-viewheadertr
  {
     display: none
  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the ListView webpart id using browser developer tools and then target that specific ListView using

```
$('#scriptWPQ1 .ms-viewheadertr').style.display="none";
```